# run time complexity of std::list::push_back()

Tags: c++, arrays, list, c++11, time-complexity

what is the run time complexity of the following code

```
std::list<int> a;
a.push_back(1); //initialize
a.push_back(2);
a.push_back(3);
std::list<int>::iterator i = a.begin();
std::cout<<*(++i); // displays 2
std::cout<<*(++i); // displays 3
```

I am writing a program currently in data mining and I need to be careful about its time-vice performance. I just had a doubt (which I didn't have before, as I did not care about time complexity in my earlier programs as they were straight forward). So on the safer side I wish to ask about the actual time complexity of adding an element to the list a. The pointer 'i' which behaves like an array in the above tempts me to doubt if its really an array or an object which has overloaded ++ and * operators.

If 'i' was to be an array, then the time complexity of std::list::push_back() should be O(n) which is not desired for my situation. But instead if its not, could you explain the algorithm carried over by the operators * and ++ so that its possible to determine their time complexity? and is it advisable to use lists for my case? (if 'i' is not an array, then its safe to assume that std::list::push_back() has time complexity O(1) )

**sorry for my previous version of the question which was not so readable**

Comment: I would think there is no array of pointers, the elements in the list point to the next (and previous) element.

Comment: Why do you think it is O(N^2)???

Comment: what about *(++i)? isn't it like accessing an array?

Comment: @chessHacker It is an iterator they have their the `*` and `++` operators overloaded. They don't behave like they are in an array. * does dereference the iterator. But it++ jumps to the next element in the list, not in an array. List elements are not by definition next to each other in memory.

Comment: @chessHacker that's like accessing an iterator. In some ways, the interface of iterators is quite similar to pointers.

Comment: I improved my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So there should be an array of pointers each pointing to each node in the linked list. Each time we call the push_back() member function, the array of pointers should be cleared and reallocated; don't you think so?

No, I don't think so. Nowhere in the standard is such array mentioned and it would be very strange to have such in a **list** container.

As a sidenote:
If such array existed, growing it would be O(n), not O(n^2). Which could make insertion amortized O(1) if it's size is multiplied when it's full such as how `std::vector` would do.

Comment: yes, but what happens when we increment i in the above case? i is a pointer, so i++ should represent the next array element right? like in i[1] which is same as *(i+1)

Comment: `i` is not a pointer, it's an iterator. `i++` represents an iterator to the next element in the list and has nothing to do with any array. The interface of iterator is very similar to a pointer (a pointer can be used as an iterator to an array, but the standard containers have iterators of other type).

Answer (score 0):

std::list is normally a doubly linked list implementation and not an array implementation.In other way std::list is a higher level abstraction of doubly linked list.